# strtod underflow, return value != 0

Tags: c, strtod

Here's my test code:

```
errno = 0;
d = strtod("1.8011670033376514e-308", NULL);
```

With this code, I get `d == 1.8011670033376514e-308` and `errno == ERANGE`.

From strtod(3):

> If the correct value would cause overflow, plus or minus `HUGE_VAL` (`HUGE_VALF`, `HUGE_VALL`) is returned (according to the sign of the value), and `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`.  If the correct value would cause underflow, zero is returned and `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`.

So, it seems to me that either `errno` should be zero (no error) or `d` should be zero (underflow).

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? This happens for many different versions of eglibc and gcc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In §7.22.1.3 *The `strtod()`, `strtof()` and `strtold()` functions*, the C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) says:

> The functions return the converted value, if any. If no conversion could be performed,
>   zero is returned. If the correct value overflows and default rounding is in effect (7.12.1),
>   plus or minus `HUGE_VAL`, `HUGE_VALF`, or `HUGE_VALL` is returned (according to the
>   return type and sign of the value), and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in
>   `errno`. If the result underflows (7.12.1), the functions return a value whose magnitude is
>   no greater than the smallest normalized positive number in the return type; whether
>   `errno` acquires the value `ERANGE` is implementation-defined.

The standard also notes in §5.2.4.2.2 *Characteristics of floating types* that IEC 60559 (IEEE 754) floating point numbers have the limit:

> ```
> DBL_MIN 2.2250738585072014E-308 // decimal constant
> ```

Since 1.8011670033376514e-308 is smaller than `DBL_MIN`, you get a sub-normal number, and `ERANGE` is quite appropriate (but optional).

On Mac OS X 10.9.4 with GCC 4.9.1, the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    double d = strtod("1.8011670033376514e-308", &end);
    if (errno != 0)
    {
        int errnum = errno;
        printf("%d: %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    }
    printf("%24.16e\n", d);
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&d;
    const char *pad = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i++)
    {
        printf("%s0x%.2X", pad, *p++);
        pad = " ";
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

produces the output:

```
34: Result too large
 1.8011670033376514e-308
0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xA8 0xF3 0x0C 0x00
```

The error message is ironically wrong — the value is too small — but you can't have everything.

Answer (score 3):

If `strtod()` returned a non-zero value (that is not +/- `HUGE_VAL`), the call has succeeded (according to the man page you quoted).

Referring to the man page for [`errno.h`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html):

> The `<errno.h>` header file defines the integer variable `errno`, which
>          is set by system calls and some library functions in the event of an
>          error to indicate what went wrong.  Its value is significant only
>          when the return value of the call indicated an error (i.e., `-1` from
>          most system calls; `-1` or `NULL` from most library functions); **a
>          function that succeeds is allowed to change `errno`.**

Thus, you can only check `errno` for an error if the return value of your function actually returns a value indicating an error has occurred.

A more complete explanation of `errno` (and an explanation of its relationship to `strtod()`) can be found [on another StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/209731/81818).

Answer (score 3):

The code is behaving according to [The Open Group's POSIX specification of `strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtod.html):

> If the correct value would cause an underflow, a value whose magnitude is no greater than the smallest normalized positive number in the return type shall be returned and errno set to [ERANGE].

I'd say what you're seeing is an error in detail in the Linux manpage.